# Where Is My Mistake? (Integration, Fourier Series)

Tags: integration, fourier-series

I am trying to calculate $c_m = \displaystyle{\int_0^1e^{-2\pi ixm} \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty  c_n e^{2\pi ixn} \, dx}$ for $m = 0$.

Here is my work:

$\displaystyle{\int_0^1e^{-2\pi ixm} \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty  c_n e^{2\pi ixn} \, dx = \int_0^1 \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty c_n e^{-2\pi ixm} e^{2\pi ixn} \, dx = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n \int_0^1 e^{-2\pi ixm} e^{2\pi ixn} \, dx}$

(I know that interchanging a sum and an integral is not always possible, but I am almost certain that through the Fubini-Tonelli Theorem it is justified here)

$\displaystyle{m = 0 \Rightarrow \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty c_n \int_0^1 e^{0} e^{2\pi ixn} \, dx = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty c_n \int_0^1 e^{2\pi ixn} \, dx = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty c_n \frac{e^{2\pi ixn}}{2 \pi in} \biggr\rvert_0^1 = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{c_n}{2 \pi in} \left( e^{2 \pi in} - e^{0} \right) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{c_n}{2 \pi in} \left( \left( \left( e^{\pi i} \right)^2 \right)^n - 1 \right) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{c_n}{2 \pi in} \left( \left( \left( -1 \right)^2 \right)^n - 1 \right) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{c_n}{2 \pi in} \left( \left( 1 \right)^n - 1 \right) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \frac{c_n}{2 \pi in} \left(1 - 1 \right) = 0}$

My source says that the answer is $\frac{1}{6}$. Where did I go wrong?

Edit: I feel like it's confusing that $m$ and $n$ look so alike, so I would like to reiterate: **It is given that $m = 0$, not $n = 0$**

Comment: I apologize in advance for any typos; I'm not in the best mood as the result of being frustrated with this question.

Comment: What is your justification for the penultimate equality? $(-1)^n = \pm 1$ depending on the parity of $n$, so why have you said that $(-1)^n =1$?

Comment: @SeraPhim It's $\left( \left( -1 \right)^2 \right)^n$. Thus, $1^n = 1$

Comment: Your integration formula $\int_0^1\exp(0\times2\pi ix)dx=(1-1)/(2\pi i 0)=0$ is wrong.

Comment: Oh yes my apologies, I misread it

Comment: @kimchilover If you are referring to $e^0e^{2\pi ixn}$, then I never simplified it as $e^{0 \times 2\pi ixn}$, as that would be wrong. The $e^0$ goes away, since $e^0$ is 1. Additionally, if I were to write it an a single exponential, it would be $e^{0 \textbf{+} 2 \pi ixn }$, not $e^{0 \times 2 \pi ixn}$

Comment: @SeraPhim All good :)

Comment: Are you computing the Fourier coefficient of the product of a constant function times a Fourier series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually told us what the function is other than it has a Fourier expansion $\sum c_ne^{2\pi inx}$, so there is no way for us to tell you how to get $c_0=\frac16$.  But let's assume you can calculate the integrals $\int_0^1 e^{2\pi imx}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ in some way.

You made a mistake with the integration of the $n=0$ term.  Specifically, when $n=0$, you can't have "divide by $n$".  Instead,
$$
e^{2\pi ix0}=1\quad\forall x
$$
so
$$
\int_0^1 e^{2\pi ix0}\,\mathrm{d}x=1,\text{ not }\left.\dfrac{e^{2\pi i0x}-1}{2\pi i0}\right\rvert_0^1.$$

Comment: I'm not assuming $n = 0$, but rather $m = 0$. So $e^{2 \pi ixn}$ never simplifies to $e^{2 \pi ix0}$, as $n$ is just an arbitrary constant in the integral, which is with respect to $x$.

Comment: Huh? $n$ is your dummy in $\sum_n c_n e^{2\pi ix n}$ which you swapped out the summation of.  Now you imposed $m=0$ in the integral so when $n=0$, which is a perfectly valid term in your sum, you get to integrate $e^{2\pi ix0}=1$ rather than $e^{2\pi ixn}$, $n\neq 0$.

Comment: Doesn't the integral take priority first? That's why I calculated the integral first and dealt with $n$ as just some constant.

Comment: No!  If it is a term in the sum, then it is there in the integral of the sum or the sum of integrals, so you need to deal with it.  You only dealt with all $n\neq 0$ but you can't use them to conclude the same must be true for $n=0$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much for your solution. I just have one final question. Does the whole thing then evaluate to $c_0$? Since the only $n$-term that doesn't end up as $0$ is $n = 0$, which ends up as 1 in the integral and the sum collapses to a single term: $c_0$.

Comment: Yes, and we have $\int_0^1 e^{-2\pi i m x} \sum_n c_ne^{2\pi i n x}\,\mathrm{d}x=c_m$ for all $m$.